# Problem on Majda's Vorticity and Incompressible Flow

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

I'm reading Majda's book, on page 110, I cannot understand how to get $v\in C_W (0,T;H^{m})$ from the above.

And he wrote "$[\phi,v^{\epsilon}]\to[\phi,v]$ uniformly on $[0,T]$ " two times, do the two bracketssquare brackets have the same meaning? Which is the dual pair on $H^{m}$ or $H^{m^{'}}$? I'm really comfused.

Any suggestions are welcome! Thank all of you!

Comment: Well, I don't have access to this book right now. However, I think I rememeber this part. Is the part where they show the local existence, right? I think that 
$$
[\phi,v]=<\phi,v>=\int \phi v dx.
$$
The dual of $H^m$ is $H^{-m}$ (use Fourier to convince yourself).

Comment: @guacho Thank you very much. But I still have some problem. As I say , he wrote that sentence two times. You mean the brackets all denote the dual pair of $H^{m}$ ? But I think the first and the second denote the dual pair of $H^{m}$ and $H^{m'}$ respectively, they are equal? Then I can understand.

Comment: The dual of $H^m$ is $H^{-m}$, and the dual of $H^{m'}$ is $H^{-m'}$, thus they are not the same. Then the brakets are always different  duality pairings. However, all them can be understood as merely the integral I wrote previously. Finally notice that 
$$
H^{-s}\subset H^{-t}\subset L^2\subset H^t\subset H^s,
$$
for $0<t<s$. Let me know if you need more help with this paragraph.

Comment: @guacho Sorry, I think I'm weak in the property of $H^{s}$ space. Why we can use this subset relationship to understand the two different pair be the $L^2$ inner product? Thank you so much for you help!

Comment: You can read all this in the book by Brezis "functional analysis".